# how to edit the string form csv in macro script

Tags: imacros

I have csv file, which is called containg list of urls and looks like this :
[image]

My script will take the screenshots for all these urls.

My code looks like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8871104 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120
SET !DATASOURCE W:\url-list-with-change-in-page-size.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=2
SET VAR1 {{!COL1}}
SET VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{VAR1}}\";  s.replace("http://",""); ")
SCREENSHOT TYPE=Page FOLDER=C:\Users\iMacros\Downloads FILE={{VAR2}}
```

This gives me an error `wrong format of SET command, line 13 (Error code: 910)`

So basically,

I have

```
{{COL1}} = http://www.webcentral.com.au/marketing/search-engine-optimisation
```

and i want

```
{{$VAR1}} = www.webcentral.com.au_marketing_search-engine-optimisation
```

With the help of `EVAL()` i want to first remove `http://` and then replace `/` with `_`.

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SET VAR2 EVAL("'{{VAR1}}'.replace('http://','').replace(/\\//g,'_');")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. Easiest would be to add one more column in your CSV with the name you want for that url. That way you dont have you manipulate the data. If you must use EVAL, you need to escape certain characters.

This works for me:

```
SET !VAR1 "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024675/how-to-edit-the-
string-form-csv-in-macro-script/28063429#28063429"
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var x=\"{{!var1}}\"; var y=x.replace(\"http://\",\"\"); y;")
PROMPT {{!VAR2}}
```